# The Community user should be proposing these changes for me

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, documentation, proposed-changes, documentation-versions

So here's my latest set of Documentation edits:

[image: That's +50, by the way.]

I kind of feel like I shouldn't be getting this much rep from these. (Admittedly not quite as much at the moment given how close I am to 3K, but…) If you look at them, they're actually all just adding the missing Python 3.6 version. To top it all off? This isn't a one-time thing. My rep graph tells me that I've done this 3 times before. This can be done *any time a version is added to any tag*.

Luckily, I have an idea: how about whenever a new version is added, the Community ♦ user proposes a change in each topic with the previous last version, that adds the new version?

Comment: I'm more curious as to how you managed to edit 17 things in the space of 2 minutes.

Comment: How'd you edit so fast? More importantly, why are your edits minor enough that you can make 17 in 2 minutes?

Comment: @NicolBolas mostly just having the drafts ready to go.

Comment: @Magisch All I did was add one version to each.

Comment: Always the same users who Approved the changes. I smell robo-reviewing.

Comment: @S.L.Barth: Once you figure out the reason for the first change, it's really not that hard to approve the rest without overthinking it. In any case, this seems like a flaw in the dual versioning system. Looks like there should be a way to say >= 2.4 and all versions of Python 3.x. That would avoid needing to update many topics each time there's a new release.